# C++ code to see what shows

Tags: c++

tell me please what does this code output and show me the pseudocode.Thank you very much.

```
void f (int x)
{ 
    if(x>0)
    { 
        cout<<'x'; | printf("%c",'x');
        f(x/3);
        cout<<'y'; | printf("%c",'y');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get a compiler for free...

Comment: Nothing, it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code is broken.

```
cout<<'x'; | printf("%c",'x');
```

is not a valid `C++` syntax. Try only `cout` or `printf`. Like this:

```
if(x>0)
{
    cout<<'x';
    f(x/3);
    cout<<'y';
}
```

> tell me please what does this code output

Compile it, you will get the output.

> show me the pseudo code

Its a simple [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) where the *base case* is

```
x <= 0
```

If the function `f ()` called with `x > 0` then it will print the char `x` and then call `f ()` again with `x/3` and print the char `x` again and so on. After the terminating case reached it will print the char `y` the total number of time  `f ()` recursively called.

Note that, *integer* division discards the decimal part. Say,

```
x = 7
x/3 = 7/3
x/3 = 2.3333333....
x/3 = 2 (0.33333 discarded)
```

So, if `-3 < x < 3` then after executing `f ()`, the recursion will terminate.